Usage of @ in JSON LD data
While seeing examples of JSON-LD Documents, I see some keys that start with @. Is there any rule that dicatates which of the keys should start with @ ?
In this example, why might one choose to use @value instead of value?
"credentialSubject": {
    "id": "did:example:ebfeb1f712ebc6f1c276e12ec21",
    "animalType": [
      {
        "@value": "Dog",
        "@language": "en"
      },
      {
        "@value": "Chien",
        "@language": "fr"
      }
    ]


These keys starting with @ are JSON-LD keywords. They are part of, and defined by, JSON-LD.

In this example, why might one choose to use @value instead of value?

When using value instead of @value (without defining value to be an alias for @value in your context),

the object would no longer be a valid Value Object (i.e., the @language would no longer be associated with the value), and
value would be interpreted according to your context (e.g., if you were using Schema.org, it would result in the property http://schema.org/value).

